# How do I find an algebraic expression for the function $F(ξ, \bar{ξ})$ from this paper?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

I am working on understanding the paper ["On $C^2$-smooth Surfaces of Constant Width" by Brendan Guilfoyle and Wilhelm Klingenberg](https://sword.cit.ie/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1023&context=dpttem_kpub). As part of their definition of equations for a 3D surface, they use a function $F(ξ, \bar{ξ})$ where $ξ$ is "the local complex coordinate on the unit 2-sphere in $^3$ obtained by stereographic projection from the south pole" and $\bar{ξ}$ is the complex conjugate of $ξ$. However, they don't explicitly state an algebraic definition for $F$ in any of the places they use it. All they do is state some conditions $F$ must satisfy, and I don't see how to derive an explicit expression from those alone.

### How do I work out an expression for $F(ξ, \bar{ξ})$?

[@Abezhiko](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4871076/530932) says that if you have a circle parameterized as $x(t) = r \cos(t), y(t) = r \sin(t)$, you can reparameterize it as $(x, y = F(x))$ with $F(x) = ±\sqrt{r^2 - x^2}$. That makes sense, and it appears to be analogous to what the authors of this paper are doing: they explain a method of finding an oriented line in 3D space based on coordinates $(ξ, η)$, then set $η = F(ξ, \bar{ξ})$ to get everything in terms of the single complex variable $ξ$. But I can't figure out an expression for $F$ based on that fact and the other conditions the authors attach to it.

### All Mentions of $F$ From the Paper

- 2.4 Line Congruences

  - "In our case, the line congruences can be parameterized by their directions. Thus we have $ξ ↦ \bigl(ξ, η = F(ξ, \bar{ξ})\bigr)$, and we label the following combination of slopes $ψ = (1 + ξ \bar{ξ})^2 \frac{∂}{∂ξ} \left(\frac{F}{(1 + ξ \bar{ξ})^2}\right)$ and $σ = -\frac{∂\bar{F}}{∂ξ}$."
  - "For this surface to be orthogonal to the lines in $^3$, the complex function $F$ must satisfy a certain condition. **Theorem 2.4:** A line congruence $\bigl(ξ, η = F(ξ, \bar{ξ})\bigr)$ is orthogonal to a surface in $^3$ if and only if there is a real function $r(ξ, \bar{ξ})$ satisfying $\frac{∂r}{∂\bar{ξ}} = \frac{2 F}{(1 + ξ \bar{ξ})^2}$."
  - "The surface can be reconstructed in $^3$ from this data be inserting $r = r(ξ, \bar{ξ})$ and $η = F(ξ, \bar{ξ})$ in equations (2.1)."
- 2.5 Focal Points of a Line Congruence

  - "Suppose we have a line congruence $Σ$ parameterized by its direction $ξ ↦ \bigl(ξ, η = F(ξ, \bar{ξ})\bigr)$. **Definition 2.5:** A point $p ∈ ^3$ on a line $γ$ in the line congruence $Σ$ is a *focal point* if the jacobian of the transformation $(ξ, r) ↦ Φ\Bigl(\bigl(ξ, F(ξ, \bar{ξ})\bigr), r\Bigr)$ vanishes at $p$. The set of focal points of a line congruence $Σ$ generically form surfaces in $^3$, which are referred to as the *focal surfaces* of $Σ$."
- 3.1 Oriented Normal lines

  - "**Proposition 3.2:** The oriented normals to a surface of constant width $w$ are given by $ξ ↦ \bigl(ξ, η = F(ξ, \bar{ξ})\bigr)$ where the lines have the reflection symmetry $F\bigl(τ(ξ), τ(\bar{ξ})\bigr) = -\frac{1}{\bar{ξ}^2} \overline{F(ξ, \bar{ξ})}$."

    - Note: $τ(ξ) = -\bar{ξ}^{-1}$ is the antipodal map.
- 4.1 Rotational Symmetry

  - "First consider the oriented normal lines to a convex surface that is rotationally symmetric about the $x^3$-axis. It is not hard to see that the map $ξ ↦ \bigl(ξ, η = F(ξ, \bar{ξ})\bigr)$ determining this line congruence satisfies $F = G(R) e^{i θ}$, where $G$ is a real function and $ξ = R e^{i θ}$."